# What password hashing algorithm does devise use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I would like to store and validate passwords in a ruby application that does not use devise, and have them be compatible with a future application that does use devise. What is the default password hashing scheme that devise uses, and is it possible to extract and use just this component from devise?

Answer (score 4):

Devise's DatabaseAuthenticatable module uses BCrpyt to hash passwords, wrapped up in the [Devise::Encryptor](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/encryptor.rb) module. The relevant method, `digest`, is pretty simple:

```
def self.digest(klass, password)
  if klass.pepper.present?
    password = "#{password}#{klass.pepper}"
  end
  ::BCrypt::Password.create(password, cost: klass.stretches).to_s
end
```

`klass` is only used to fetch a couple parameters: `pepper`, a string which is appended onto the password pre-hashing but **not** stored in the database (unlike salt, which is appended as well but stored with the password in the DB); and `cost`, a measure of how secure the hash should be (see [the docs](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby#cost-factors)). Both of these are static and you can hard-code them into your non-Devise app (but make sure to keep `pepper` secret!).

So, your hash method might be written just as:

```
def self.digest(password)
  password = "#{password}#{ENV['PASSWORD_PEPPER']}"
  ::BCrypt::Password.create(password, cost: 10).to_s
end
```

Comment: The pepper is the same across all users?

Comment: Shouldn't this be randomly assigned from a range? and then each of the possible values tested when verifiying the password? Can it also use a salt?

Comment: Pepper is the same for all users, but not stored in the database (i.e., not stored with the hashes). Salt is generated randomly per user (by Bcrpyt, hence why there's no mention of it above), but stored with the hash. The combination of both gives some additional security, as an attacker would need both your database and your codebase in order to do a brute-force attack.

Comment: I forgot to mention -- if you look at the Encryptor module, when checking an entered password against the stored one, it uses the BCrypt library to pull the salt out of the hash and get the digest.